# Issue when accessing PostgreSQL 15 in pgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, postgresql-15

Getting the following error when trying to access PostgreSQL 15 in pgAdmin 4 for the first time. Is this because I've messed up the passwords?

Error message: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections? connection to server at "localhost" (::1),port 5432 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Any advice on solutions/ next steps would be ideal!

Comment: Did you install Postgres, or did you only install pgAdmin? If you did install Postgres, is it actually running?